# CMD commands to restart Windows Update (Just searching for Info)

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-update

So. A friend of mine has a problem with windows update and found some commands that are supposed to resolve the problem, and I tryed to find some info about those commands, just to know exactly what the do but I didn't find anything about it. I'm not saying they are some kind of bad thing, I'm just trying to find some info to know what is behind this.

```
net stop wuauserv
net stop cryptSvc
net stop bits
net stop msiserver
Ren C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old
Ren C:\Windows\System32\catroot2 Catroot2.old
net start wuauserv
net start cryptSvc
net start bits
net start msiserver
```

I know it stops services, renames some folder and restarts those services, but I am just curious what exactly all this is.

Comment: I think the one you're looking for, is `wuauserv`, the Windows Update something server.

Comment: Type `net help start`. Type `ren /?`. For a list of services `sc query` which includes a display name. `wmic service get name,displayname,description,startmode,started /format:list` includes a description. PS `sc start` replaces `net start`.